# Perl graphic display while copying files

Tags: perl, graphics

I am copying a bunch of files using [`File::NCopy`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aNCopy) from one location to another to another recursively. I have used a `print` statement as follows to support the status of the copying files.

```
my $cp = File::NCopy->new(recursive => 1);
$cp->copy("$source_dir/*", $target_dir) or die "Could not perform rcopy of $source_dir to $target_dir: $!";
print "Copying completed from $source_dir to $target_dir\n";
```

Is there any way I can insert a graphic in the above lines to convey the amount of files copied and amount of files left to be copied? Or at least a moving line which conveys that the process is going on?

Comment: Have you seen this script: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=File%20copy%20progress%2e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind a lot of output – a line of text per file copied – you can enable the module's debug mode using

```
$cp->{_debug} = 1
```

before calling the `copy` method.

Comment: But he asked for graphics, not text.

Comment: I am suggesting the only solution I can think of using the `File::NCopy` module. Because the `copy` method is atomic there is no other way of checking progress until the process completes.

Comment: Yes, that is his actual problem.  Accept the copies as atomic, so there is no indication of work for each file -- or rewrite the low level copying procedure, which involves effort and maybe a performance hit just to get an indicator.

Comment: @Paul Can you please elaborate as I don't get your last answer..Thank you

Comment: @deep You want to provide an indicator of how the copy is progressing, but the subroutine for copying files, copies all the files, and then returns, in one step.  Borodin's answer is that only the debug option of the subroutine provides a progress indicator as debugging text.  Alternatively, you could write your own copying subroutine, copying files one at a time instead of using the subroutine in File::NCopy.  Depending on how you wrote this, it could do whatever you want graphically, but it would take effort, risk bugs, and possibly be slower than File::NCopy.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `Term::ProgressBar` can do the job.

[Term::ProgressBar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aProgressBar)

Comment: And how is that to be combined with a call to the `File::NCopy` module?

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding. The combination is impossible unless we modify `File::NCopy` module. To achieve your objective with `Term::ProgressBar`, we need know the total number of files to be copied and the current number of files that have been copied.

Comment: @Borodin You are right as I don't know the number of files in the contained folders (Also, I am doing it recursively)..@Yuni Thank you for your input